# Cannot get my N300 (DWA-130) D-link wireless USB to work on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I'll start by saying i'm pretty new to linux, go easy on me!

I've downloaded Ndiswrapper and tried installing the windows XP/Vista driver...

But `iwconfig` shows that there is no extensions..

I've looked around on the site and found this

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qjc87hzk1z5x6z0/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script
--2014-12-23 13:16:00--  https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qjc87hzk1z5x6z0/wireless_script
```

which resulted in this log file: 
Please help!! I'm entirely lost!

```
======== Wireless-Info START ========
```

System-Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
mouthbuster-MS-7900 3.13.0-39-generic x86_64,  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, trusty

CPU    : AMD A10-6800K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Memory : 7860 MB
Uptime : 13:16:01 up 20 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.42, 0.28, 0.19
```

lspci ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7900]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
```

lsusb ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1532:0016 Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2001:3c25 D-Link Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

PCMCIA Card Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

iwconfig ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

rfkill ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

lsmod ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
ndiswrapper           283985  0 
wmi                    19177  0
```

module parameters ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
ndiswrapper   (6): 
wmi           (2): debug_dump_wdg=N | debug_event=N
```

nm-tool ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
State: connected (global)
=======================o=======o========o===========o=========o===========o==============o===========
 Interface & ID        | Type  | Driver | State     | Default | Speed     | Support      | HW Addr   
=======================o=======o========o===========o=========o===========o==============o===========
 eth0  [Auto Ethernet] | Wired | alx    | connected | yes     | 1000 Mb/s |              | <MAC eth0>

    Address:         192.168.0.17
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1
    DNS:             64.71.255.204
    DNS:             64.71.255.198
-----------------------+-------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------
```

NetworkManager.state ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

NetworkManager.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC eth0>,
```

[ifupdown]

```
managed=false
```

NM WiFi Profiles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

interfaces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

resolv.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Routes & Ping ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---

```
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.735/1.117/1.500/0.383 ms
```

--- 127.0.1.1 ping statistics ---

```
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.026/0.031/0.036/0.005 ms
```

iw reg get ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
(Region : "en_US.UTF-8")
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
```

iwlist chan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
       -
```

iwlist scan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

blacklist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci
```

modinfo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[ndiswrapper]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/ndiswrapper.ko
version:        1.59
srcversion:     DC1EFD919FDF2DB80D424C6
depends:        
parm:           if_name:Network interface name or template (default: wlan%d) (charp)
parm:           proc_uid:The uid of the files created in /proc (default: 0). (int)
parm:           proc_gid:The gid of the files created in /proc (default: 0). (int)
parm:           debug:debug level (int)
parm:           hangcheck_interval:The interval, in seconds, for checking if driver is hung. (default: 0) (int)
parm:           utils_version:Compatible version of utils (read only: 1.9) (charp)

[wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/wmi.ko
srcversion:     CED5410F008DC70DF5F064B
depends:        
parm:           debug_event:Log WMI Events [0/1] (bool)
parm:           debug_dump_wdg:Dump available WMI interfaces [0/1] (bool)
```

udev rules ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
# PCI device 0x1969:0xe091 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Custom files/entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
/etc/modules        : Not Default
/etc/rc.local       : Default
/etc/modprobe.d     : Not Default
/etc/pm/(cnf|pw|sl) : Default

[/etc/modules]
lm78

[/etc/modprobe.d]
iwlwifi.conf      : remove iwlwifi \
                    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
                    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
mlx4.conf         : softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
```

Kernel boot line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=20c30937-34cc-43e1-8a5c-cc1ae47f62f1 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

dmesg ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[    0.615296] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    0.615616] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.966209] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [<MAC eth0>]
[   16.470977] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   18.464117] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  367.914947] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[  368.114462] ndiswrapper (check_nt_hdr:141): kernel is 64-bit, but Windows driver is not 64-bit;bad magic: 010B
[  368.114470] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'rt2870'
[  368.115193] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver rt2870; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'

======== Done ========
```

Comment: Please run again: lsusb. Is the device ID of 2001:3c25 correct?

Comment: Yes sir ! 2001:3c25 it is

Comment: Before I propose a solution, are you able to paste the Windows XP .inf file you used here? http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your response. Thanks.

Comment: I feel like i did that wrong.. but here you go hahaa http://paste.ubuntu.com/9605157/

Comment: No problem. I wanted to see the text of the file itself. Please try: cat RT2870.inf > wifi.txt. Find the file wifi.txt and paste it as above.

Comment: Sorry ! didnt realize you commented.. I don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: I think this is it ! http://paste.ubuntu.com/9605460/

Comment: Please run this command: cat ~/Desktop/Win/Drivers/XP_VISTAX86/RT2870.inf  >  wifi.txt Now look in your user directory and find the text file wifi.txt. Paste it here and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Please see my answer in a few moments.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the device and in a terminal, do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf
```

Add one long single line:

```
install rt2800usb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb $CMDLINE_OPTS; /bin/echo "2001 3c25" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Caps, brackets, punctuation, etc. are crucial. Proofread twice, save and close the text editor. Insert the device. If it doesn't start immediately, you might have to do:

```
sudo modprobe rt2800usb
```

Be certain that ndiswrapper is removed:

```
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils*
```

It may take a reboot.

Comment: Did everything as above and still no eth0, lo extensions ! What is going on :(

Comment: disregard !!! got it working now, thanks SO SO SO much !!!!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it. Glad it's working.

Answer (score -1):

You have an USB stick, so ignore all the output relating the problem to any PCI related problems.

And I am giving a solution not using ndiswrapper - ndiswrapper was a great tool when linux did not support Wifi modules properly, but it is slightly outdated and not recommended any longer. So please try the following instead:

In your lsusb output, it says

```
Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2001:3c25 D-Link Corp.
```

Which means that the ID of your USB Wifi device is 2001:3c25, which implies that it uses a Ralink rt27xx/rt28xx/rt30xx chipset. These should be supported under Ubuntu. However, you may need to install the nonfree firmwares to load the kernel modules correctly. You can do so by entering

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

in the terminal. You can then try to load the module - or simply restart, which may be simpler. The module will be loaded automatically.

Comment: The firmware for rt2800usb is not included in linux-firmware-nonfree. As well, linux-firmware-nonfree is deprecated.

Comment: I uninstalled my rt2780 driver, installed the nonfree firmware and restarted. But still nothing under iwconfig

Comment: Sorry, Chili555 was right, and I was mistaken - the firmware is not part of linux-firmware-nonfree. Could you please show the output of your modules list? I.e. run lsmod|grep rt to only include the possible candidates?

Comment: uhhhh, is this what you're looking for ?                              mouthbuster@mouthbuster-MS-7900:~$ lsmod | grep rt
parport_pc             32701  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc

Comment: Ok ... since I do not have a RALink wifi device lying around, I cannot test this myself ... but you should look here: [http://www.teamxlink.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?p=233117] The name of the device is a different one, but the chipset should be the same. (Oh, and ignore the last entry installing Kai - once the Wifi is up and running, Unity should tell you so.) Good luck!

Comment: I don't know how to do this :( sorry for needing so much help !!
Code:
install rt2800usb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb; /bin/echo "2019 ed14" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id

In the above, you need to type model name, vendor ID and productID of your wireless network adapter.
i don't know where to put the model name, venor ID or ProductID Nor what they are...

Comment: I will be happy to propose the permanent solution but I'd love to see the RT2870.inf file contents first.