# Cannot get D-Link 131

Tags: wireless

I tried the instructions provided here:

[Cannot get my N300 (DWA-130) D-link wireless USB to work on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564716/cannot-get-my-n300-dwa-130-d-link-wireless-usb-to-work-on-ubuntu-14-04)

and here:

[How to install a wireless adapter D-Link DWA-131?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591016/how-to-install-wireless-adapter-d-link-dwa-131)

This suggests that if you have Hardware Ver E1 and Firmware 5.00 device ID your stuffed.

Is this the case?  Like so many others I purchased this device after checking that it was compatible with Linux yet got caught by firmware changes.  Is their any way to avoid being caught like this again?  Can I run it with an older version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.